# Does $a!b!$ always divide $(a+b)!$

Tags: group-theory, factorial

Hello the question is as stated above and is given to us in the context of group theory, specifically under the heading of isomorphism and products. I would write down what I have tried so far but I have made very little progress in trying to solve this over the last few hours!

Comment: If it were me I would write "Yes it does, it's a binomial coefficient", context be damned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hint: Find an injective group homomorphism $S_a \times S_b \hookrightarrow S_{a+b}$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean a group injection, not a set injection.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: ahhhh so if i define an injective homomorphism then $S_a \times S_b$ will be isomorphic to the image which is then a subgroup of $S_{a+b}$ and so it is a divisor. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

The number of ways to choose $a$ objects out of $a+b$ objects if order matters in the selection is $(a+b)\times(a+b-1)\times\cdots\times((a+b)-(a-1))=\frac{(a+b)!}{b!}$, since there are $a+b$ ways to choose the first object, $a+b-1$ ways to choose the second object from the remaining ones, and so on.

However, $a!$ permutations actually correspond to a single combination (where order is immaterial), since $a$ objects can be arranged in $a!$ ways. This means that $\frac{(a+b)!}{b!}=ka!$ for some integer $k$, so that $(a+b)!=ka!b!$.

Comment: Isn't this kind of circular reasoning?  How do we know that formula is the number of ways to choose $a$ objects out of $a+b$ objects?  Can you prove this without proving the formula yields an integer along the way?

Comment: This still feels like it leaves out the important details... like someone asking "Why does the order of a subgroup divide the order of the group" and someone answering "Because of Lagrange's theorem."

Comment: I think your edit made it less clear.

Comment: I really like this solution...It's with posts like this that I wish I could up-vote twice! ;-)

Answer (score 10):

A proof based on the binomial recurrence: $\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!} ( =\binom{a+b}{a}) =: f(a,b)$ fulfills the following recurrence:

$f(a,b) = f(a-1,b) + f(a,b-1), \quad a>0,b>0$

with starting values

$f(a,0) = f(0,a) = 1, \quad a \ge 0$

so by induction for all non-negative integer values $a,b$ the function $f(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$ is an integer value.

Comment: It's good that you show the definition of the combinatorial parenthetically. It's really incidental to the question posed.

Answer (score 4):

A proof based on prime factorization:

Let $e(N,p)$, $p$ a prime, be the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $N$. Then we have to show:

For all primes $p$: $e(a!,p)+e(b!,p) \le e((a+b)!,p)$.

We have

$e(n!,p) = [\frac{n}{p}] + [\frac{n}{p^2}] + \cdots, \quad$ where $[r]$ is the largest integer $\le r$.

We also have

$[\frac{a}{k}] + [\frac{b}{k}] \le [\frac{a+b}{k}] \quad$  for any positive integers $a,b,k$.

From these two propositions the claim follows directly.

Comment: If we define $\sigma_p(n)$ to be the sum of the base-$p$ digits of $n$, then $$e(n!,p)=\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}$$

Comment: @robjohn and coproc: Would you mind giving proofs for both of your expressions for $e(n!,p)$?

Comment: @Hansen: my formula is proven in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901).