# Looking for a non-combinatorial proof that $a! \cdot b! \mid (a+b)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, factorial, alternative-proof

(I use $a$ and $b$ to denote natural numbers.)

> **Question.** Without appealing to the combinatorial interpretation of $$\frac{(a+b)!}{a! b!}$$ as a multinomial coefficients, is there a proof that for all $a$ and $b$, we have $$a! \cdot b! \mid (a+b)! \qquad?$$
>
> Basically, I want a proof that just uses some clever algebra.

I was thinking that maybe we can use modular arithmetic, and try to understand the value of $(a+b)!$ modulo $a! \cdot b!$, and eventually show that this is $0$.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Marlu [once](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290801/does-ab-always-divide-ab/290806#290806) suggested using the obvious injective group map $S_a × S_b → S_{a+b}$. Do you consider this combinatorial?

Comment: @k.stm, its too combinatorial to classify as an answer, but also sounds very interesting. I'd be curious to see that reference, for sure. **Edit.** Thanks, that is a nice argument.

Comment: Anything wrong with proving the recursive formula?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, that sounds good.

Answer (score 10):

You can use $\nu_{p}(n!)=\sum \limits_{k\ge 1}\left[\dfrac{n}{p^k}\right]$ and that $[a+b]\ge [a]+[b]$

Comment: What does those square brackets mean?

Comment: @goblin: Old-fashioned notation for the floor function.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks. And just be completely certain, I'm assuming $\nu_p(m)$ is the number of factors of $p$ in the prime factorization of $m$?

Comment: @goblin: Yes, it is.

Comment: @bof, k.stm linked to a similar question. I don't think they're perfect dupes though, and I'm hopeful that more interesting stuff will be posted here.

Answer (score 9):

If we use as a lemma that the product of $k$ consecutive integers is divisible by $k!$ (proven e.g. here: [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)), we see that $(a+b)!/a!$ factors into the $b$ consecutive integers $a+1,\ldots,a+b$, hence is divisible by $b!$. Then $a!b!|(a+b)!$.

Comment: More directly, $(a+b)!$ factors in sequences of $a$ and $b$ consecutive integers. This immediately generalizes to the multinomial coefficients.

Comment: Huh, didn't think that far. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the answer that you don't want:

$$\frac{(a+0)!}{a!\cdot 0!}=1=\frac{(0+b)!}{0!\cdot b!}$$

and

$$\frac{(a+b)!}{a!\cdot b!}=\frac{(a+b)(a+b-1)!}{a!\cdot b!}=\frac{(a-1+b)!}{(a-1)!\cdot b!}+\frac{(a+b-1)!}{a!\cdot (b-1)!}.$$

Then by induction, Pascal's triangle is made of integers.

Answer (score 2):

With the settings

\begin{align*}
[k]_q:=\frac{1-q^k}{1-q}\qquad\text{and}\qquad [k]_q!:=\prod_{j=1}^{k}[j]_q=\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1-q^j}{1-q}
\end{align*}

the *[q-binomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html)* $\begin{bmatrix}a+b\\a\end{bmatrix}_q$ is defined as

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}a+b\\a\end{bmatrix}_q:=\frac{[a+b]_q!}{[a]_q![b]_q!}
\end{align*}

> Since the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \begin{bmatrix}a+b\\a\end{bmatrix}_q&=\begin{bmatrix}a+b-1\\a\end{bmatrix}_q+q^{b}\begin{bmatrix}a+b-1\\a-1\end{bmatrix}_q\\
> \begin{bmatrix}a\\0\end{bmatrix}_q&=\begin{bmatrix}a\\a\end{bmatrix}_q=1
> \end{align*}
>   the $q$-binomial coefficients are polynomials in $q$ with non-negative integer coefficients.
>
> Together with
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}=\lim_{q\rightarrow 1}\begin{bmatrix}a+b\\a\end{bmatrix}_q
> \end{align*}
>
> the claim $a!b!|(a+b)!$ follows.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a truly beautiful proof by Tim Gowers](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/are-these-the-same-proof/).

And [a similar question has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial).