# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, then $a!b!|(a+b)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading the first chapter (about divisibility) of *Elementary Theory of Numbers* by *W.Sierpinski* and I stumbled upon the following exercise:

> Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, then $a!b!|(a+b)!$

the book provide an answer that rely on the fact that the theorem is true if at least one of the numbers $a$ and $b$ is equal to 1, since for each
natural $b$ we have $(b+1)!=b!(b+1)$, whence $1!b!|(1+b)!$. And by using induction the theorem is proved to be true for all natural $a$ and $b$.

I'm curious if there is annother answer that doesn't rely on induction.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Does $a!b!$ always divide $(a+b)!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290801/does-ab-always-divide-ab/290819)

Comment: If you can use that binomial coefficient ${n\choose m}$ is integer for all $m,n\geq 0,m\leq n$ then it follows almost immediately from that fact.